# PUT request only occurs on second attempt

Tags: express, mongoose

I have an express route that changes a Post's "checked" value to it's opposite boolean value (true => false, false => true). For some reason, the API return the opposite of what is in the DB. If I do a GET request after a PUT request, I get the opposite boolean value of what the PUT route gives me, which is accurate to the state of the DB.

Here is the route. Anyone see what's going on here?

```
app.put('/posts/:id', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Post.findById( id )
        .then(post => {
            if(!post) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Post not found' }); 
            }
            return Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { "checked": !post.checked })
            })
            .then(result => {
                return res.status(202).json(result.apiRepr())
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({ message: "There was a problem"}) 
                }
            });
});
```

It appears the .findByIdAndUpdate part IS updating the DB, but then the object below that gets returned is still the old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate) return the original document, you have to set the `new` option to true in order to get the modified document rather than the original:

```
return Post.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { "checked": !post.checked }, { new: true }) ...
```

`findByIdAndUpdate` [Api doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: I JUST figured that out. Thanks. This is the answer.